# Detect city from coordinates

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I need to know how to detect which city has certain coordinates. 
Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572/latitude-longitude-database) which apparently links to an open database of city lat lons.  You can load that into your postgis database and then check out [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2061/postgis-nearest-point-on-a-linestring-to-a-given-point) to find the nearest to a given point.