# Writing PyQGIS Output to Shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis

I'm trying to find the closest point on a line to another point as in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45123/moving-points-onto-lines-neighborhood). However when I try to write the result as a shapefile I get an error:

> TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.addFeature(QgsFeature,
>   QgsFeatureRendererV2 renderer=None, QGis.UnitType
>   outputUnit=QGis.Meters): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Point'

```
import shapely
from shapely.wkt import *
from shapely.geometry import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

lineLayer = iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)
pointLayer =  iface.mapCanvas().layer(1)
canvas =  iface.mapCanvas()
spIndex = QgsSpatialIndex()
lineIter =  lineLayer.getFeatures()

provider = pointLayer.dataProvider()
fields = provider.fields()
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter('Test.shp', 'CP1250', fields, provider.geometryType(), provider.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
for lineFeature in lineIter:
    spIndex.insertFeature(lineFeature)
pointIter =  pointLayer.getFeatures()
for feature in pointIter:
    ptGeom = feature.geometry()
    pt = feature.geometry().asPoint()
    nearestIds = spIndex.nearestNeighbor(pt,1)
    featureId = nearestIds[0]
    nearestIterator = lineLayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(featureId))
    nearFeature = QgsFeature()
    nearestIterator.nextFeature(nearFeature)
    shplyLineString = shapely.wkt.loads(nearFeature.geometry().exportToWkt())
    shplyPoint = shapely.wkt.loads(ptGeom.exportToWkt())
    dist = shplyLineString.distance(shplyPoint)
    shplySnapPoint = shplyLineString.interpolate(shplyLineString.project(shplyPoint))
    snapGeometry = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(shapely.wkt.dumps(shplySnapPoint))
    r = QgsRubberBand(canvas,QGis.Point)
    r.setColor(Qt.red)
    r.setToGeometry(snapGeometry,pointLayer)
    writer.addFeature(shplySnapPoint)
del writer
```

Comment: After a quick browse of your code it seems like the object shplySnapPoint from shplyLineString.interpolate is of type shapely.geometry.point.Point. The write.addFeature takes a QgsFeature / QgsPoint as argument. Try parsing the shapely geometry to a QgsPoint and use that object in the addFeature method. Pseudocode (have not used shapely before): qgsSnapPoint = QgsPoint(shplySnapPoint.x(),shplySnapPoint.y())

Answer (score 2):

After a quick browse of your code it seems like the object shplySnapPoint from shplyLineString.interpolate is of type shapely.geometry.point.Point. The write.addFeature takes a QgsFeature / QgsPoint as argument. Try parsing the shapely geometry to a QgsPoint and use that object in the addFeature method. Pseudocode (have not used shapely before):

```
qgsSnapPoint = QgsPoint(shplySnapPoint.x(),shplySnapPoint.y())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you type a help (Python Console) of **QgsVectorFileWriter.addFeature**:

```
help(QgsVectorFileWriter.addFeature)
Help on built-in function addFeature:

addFeature(...)
    QgsVectorFileWriter.addFeature(QgsFeature, QgsFeatureRendererV2 renderer=None, QGis.UnitType outputUnit=QGis.Meters) -> bool
```

you get something equivalent to 'your error'. So, the object **shplySnapPoint** is not a **QgsFeature** class object in:

```
writer.addFeature(shplySnapPoint)
```

You have to fix this.